# Setting numeric variables in a script ("set $i 1") not working ("echo $i" empty)

Tags: bash

As the title says I need help with a bash script that has to generate a string given two numeric variables. That string will be used to generate a file name, but when I test the name generation code it yields nothing

The script is the code that follows

```
# !usr/bin
set nombre
declare -a i
declare -a j

set $i  1
set $j  2

set nombre "$i\_$j.txt"

echo $i
echo $j
```

Here is what it yields:

```
entropy@3PY:~$ ./test4
```

As you can see it yields nothing while it should yield

```
1
2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: As an aside -- you might want `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as your shebang, or `#!/bin/sh` if you really wanted to write POSIX sh instead of bash (despite the question being tagged for the latter). `#!/usr/bin` isn't a valid shebang, nor is `# !usr/bin`, and a script starting with either of those won't run correctly when started from something other than a shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`set` is not used to assign values to regular variables; it is used to set the values of the positional parameters or to modify shell options. You need a regular assignment.

```
i=1
j=2
nombre="${i}_$j.txt"

echo "$i"
echo "$j"
echo "$nombre"
```

There is no need to declare variables prior to assignment; assignment creates a variable if necessary. The `declare` command is more about setting *attributes* on a name (`-a`, for instance, would mark the variable as an array variable, something you do *not* need here).

---

As an example of how `set` *does* work, consider

```
echo "First positional parameter: $1"
echo "Second positional parameter: $2"
set foo bar  # $1=foo, $2=bar
echo "First positional parameter: $1"
echo "Second positional parameter: $2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code works as desired?

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
j=2

echo $i
echo $j

nombre=$i"_"$j.txt

echo $nombre
```